# Infinity Scroll not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

For my `profile_page.php`, by default, 10 posts (10 rows from the db) are shown to the user. If the user has more than 10 posts, and scrolls to the bottom of the page, the div should expand to show the remaining posts (10 maximum). So if a user has 13 posts in total, 10 are shown by default, and then when a user scrolls to the bottom, the remaining three will show.

That's the idea, but unfortunately, my scroll just is not working. The page realizes it has reached the bottom of the page and performs the `alert("bottom`)` but does not load more posts.

**Here is infinity_scroll.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var load = 0;   
    var postLen = $('.userposts_panel').find('.message_wrapper').length;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            // start AJAX
            if(postLen >= 10){
                load++;
                $.post("inc/ajax.php", {load:load},function (data){
                $(".userposts_panel").append(data); //  class
                        alert ("bottom");
                });
            } // if closed
        } // if closed
        });
    });
```

The structure of my HTML in which the posts are displayed (simplified version):

```
<div class="userposts_panel">
   // below is the div in which each post is displayed
  <?php echo "<div class='message_wrapper'> </div> ?>
</div>
```

Seeing as the `alert()` works, I am beginning to think there is an issue with my `ajax.php` - but I just cannot find any problems.

**Here is ajax.php (again, simplified version):**

```
$load = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['load']))*10;
$query = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by='$user' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$load.",10");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $message_content = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['post_details'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $attachent       = $row['attachment'];

    echo "<div class='message_wrapper'>
      // this is where I will depict all info such as author of post etc.
    </div>";
}
?>
```

Is anyone able to identify why more data is not being loaded when I reach the bottom of my page?

**Edit**:

**Chrome console.log(data)**
[image]

**Firefox console.log(data)**
[image]

Comment: what does "data" (in your ajax callback) contain? (try to console.log it)

Comment: you can either `console.log(data);` like @JimL said or you can use the browser inspection tool and add a line break on the alert and see what `data` is that way. Alert is showing regardless if the request was successful or not. Does your console have any errors in it?

Comment: You should also make sure you don't send another request until the last one don't finish;

Comment: @gmaniac - Hi. I have never really used `console.log()` before, but I have just played around the inpection tab in Chrome. I don't know if this is what you was after, but I have edited the question with an image of the console tab.

Comment: to use `console.log` add this line `console.log(data);` before your `alert("bottom");` This will dump whatever is in that variable that is being passed back. You will see this in that `Console` tab you took a screenshot of after that post what it dumps.

Comment: @gmaniac - I have `console.log(data);` right above my `alert("bottom")`. And it still shows the same as the print screen?

Comment: for using chrome's dev tools here is a link to opening it and what it should look like https://goo.gl/Zhw7Zf then you have a couple options. You can either go to the `Networks` tab and it will show you request (what is being sent and received) in your ajax call or you can go to the `Scripts` tab and find that `alert("bottom");' and add a line break by clicking by the line number on the left. Then when that function fires it will stop and show you what is being passed around in there.

Comment: what does it show if you click `Show all messages.`?

Comment: Also, did you refresh the page after adding the `console.log()` I sometimes forget to do that when adding my dumps to a page.

Comment: @Freddy please make sure that `if(postLen >= 10){` is true in order to execute ajax request;

Comment: @gmaniac - When I click `Show all messages`, it just takes me to the `All` tab (next to `Error`). And yes, I have refreshed the page several times (even shut down the computer on the whole), still the same result. I have even tried it on Firefox browser, I have edited my question to show those results.

Comment: join this room and I will try to help you through this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106743/infinity-scroll-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Check this scroll and try it

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, `if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {` (your code) performs the same as `if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){` (my code). As in I cannot see any changes.